# Vue2 / Vue Router: Set data from navigation guards

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

This should be fairly simple but I can't figure it out. I'd like to set a value from within vue router's navigation guards. I don't even really care anymore to where this value goes, just *somewhere*. Could be on App root, could be to a component. Wherever.
So far I've tried:

```
router.beforeResolve((to, from, next) => {

// this throws Warning "Method "setValue" has type "boolean" in the component definition. Did you reference the function correctly?"
  MyComponent.methods.setValue(true);

// this works, but only here
  next(vm=>{ vm.value=true });
});

router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  // no vm. Same error on component method.
});
```

I would really like to avoid using Vuex, since (so far) it's only one feeble value that I'd like to pass. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think this is a good practice to set `value` from Vue-Router. You should pass props down. Take a look at the docs: https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode

Comment: Thanks @AdamOrlov, I am using that already. I want to specifically react to the router events (before resolve, after each) and pass something to a component above the router-view